# Usage of the word "run athwart"

Tags: word-usage

What is the meaning of **run athwart**? Does it mean **run contrary** or **fly in the face**?

Sentence:

However, defendant USA Northeast Province of Society of Jesus (hereinafter referred to as "defendant") opposes the application, arguing that the anonymity protection sought by plaintiff would **run athwart** of defendant's basic due process rights.

This sentence appears in a judgment -

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.casemine.com/judgement/us/5dd3ad72342cca69bd87a315/amp

Comment: Definition is in the dictionary "so as to be perverse or contradictory."

Comment: Should the word "run" accompany athwart in all sentence?

Comment: Look at the examples in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of run athwart?

In this context, it means "in opposition to" - definition 3 in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/athwart). Allowing the plaintiff anonymity would go against the rights of the defendant.